# Feedback on my Model Layer Approach Symfony 2 Model Layer + Doctrine

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

Please provide feedback on the following approach of creating a Model Layer which consists of business rules which utliises Doctrine for data access.

My current approach is based around the notion that the Model is a ContainerAware class / object where all the non-library, business specific domain logic is in.

I find that I have to hammer Frameworks to do things this way, which is why part of my brain questions my approach.

I'm currently using Symfony 2 which, like all modern PHP MVC frameworks, utilise an ORM layer like Doctrine 2 and inevitably regards it as the Model Layer. I'm guessing the situation will be similar with ZF2, so although my example is written in SF2, regard this as a framework agnostic question.

**Concrete Example**

As a concrete example, consider the following scenario:

**A Message Requirement**

- As a user, I can create a Message that belongs to me.
- As a user, I can update a Message that belongs to me.
- As a user, I can archive a Message that belongs to me.

**The Controller**

In Symfony2, these requirements are coded up as Actions in the controller layer.
*I'll skip the extraneous code which checks if a message actually belongs to a user, but obviously, this should be part of the domain logic also. In a method "belongsToUser" or similar.*

```
 // Vendor\MessageBundle\DefaultController 
 public function archiveAction(Request $request) {
    // ... 
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getManager();
    $message = $em->getRepository('MessageBundle:Message');
                    ->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('MessageBundle:Message')
                    ->find($request->get('id'));
    $message->setIsArchived(true);
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
    $this->flashMessage('Message has been archived.');
    // ...
}
```

**The Model**

If I was to put this into a model, it would look like the following:

```
class MessageModel 
{
     public function archive($messageId) {
     // ... 
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getManager();
        $message = $em->getRepository('MessageBundle:Message')
                    ->find($messageId);
        $message->setIsArchived(true);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
     // ... return true on success, false on fail.
     }
}
```

**Revised Controller**

My Revised Controller will now look like this:

```
 // Vendor\MessageBundle\DefaultController 
 public function archiveAction(Request $request) {
    // ... 
    $model = new MessageModel(); // or a factory.
    $result = $model->archive($request->get('id'));
    if($result) {
        $this->flashMessage('Message has been archived.');
    } else { 
        $this->flashMessage('Message could not be archived due to a system error.');
    }
    return array('result'=>$result);
    // ...
}
```

The other two requirements will also be implemented on the model.

**My Approach in a nutshell**

In a nutshell, this is my current approach:

- **Controller** - less logic
- **View** - stays the same
- **Model** - container aware and houses all business logic, accesses Doctrine as data access.
- **ORM** - Regarded as part of the Model Layer, but not regarded as THE model layer.
- **Service Layer** - when required, I can use the Service Layer to work with multiple layers, but I've found that I've only had to use it in a few occasions due to the simple nature of the applications I've had to build.

**My Question(s)**

- Is my approach in line with what others are doing?
- Am I missing something glaringly obvious?
- Have you tried anything similar to this and found it good / bad?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

At first you can use a [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) to simplify your controller. An exception is automatically thrown if the entity is not found.

I would call the message methods `archive` and `restore` but that's a matter of preference.

A nice way to integrate security checks is provided by [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/method_security_authorization#access-control-via-di-configuration). Use [ACLs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) to check wether your current user is allowed to archive a message.

Your `MessageModel` is similar to the `Manager` ([interface/abstract](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Model) and i.e. doctrine ODM/ORM [implementation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Doctrine/UserManager.php)) pattern you can find in the FOSUserBundle.

These managers are building the bridge between storage layer and your controller and all share the same Interface (i.e. [`UserManagerInterface`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManagerInterface.php)). This way you can exchange i.e. doctrine with propel easily.

Improve by turning your controller into a service and injecting your `Manager` service  instead of injecting the whole container (i.e. by extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`) and getting it from there.

You should inject only the dependencies you need into your services to ease testing.
In the example of doctrine orm/odm a manager service would retrieve the classname parameter, the entity-/documentmanager service, and the repository service. ([service definition](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/orm.xml#L8))

You can find additional inspiration for creating a controller-utilities service in Benjamin Eberlei's blog post "[Extending Symfony2: Controller Utilities](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/06/27/extending_symfony2__controller_utilities.html)".

Another often used technique is to create an abstract [parent service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html) for your most commonly used controller dependencies. ([example](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurAbstractControllerBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.xml#L32))

The last quick tip i have is moving the creation of flashmessages to [event listeners/subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#after-filters-with-the-kernel-response-event). Just check wether the method returns an object of type `Message` or better `MessageInterface` and add the success-flashmessage. If the entity is not found you can catch the exception and add the flashmessage with the error message.

You could even ommit the `return` at the end of the method when using a view response listener like [FOSRestBundle's](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/EventListener/ViewResponseListener.php#L72) that automatically assumes you're returning the original argument if the method returns nothing - read about it [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#view-response-listener).

Finally you can end up with a method in a nicely testable controller service that looks like this:

```
/** 
 * @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#message, 'ARCHIVE')")
 */
public function archiveAction(Message $message) 
{
    $message->archive();
    $this->messageManager->update($message, true);
}
```

The `manager->update()` method behaves like the one found in [FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Doctrine/UserManager.php) in my example.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to provide recommendations for SF2.

Comment: For clarity, I'll state here that the MessageModel (along with other classes/objects in this layer) is more than just a bridge between the controller and the ORM.

I see it more as a representation of business logic. So the controller does very little apart from calling on the necessary model method to execute based on the Action requested.

Comment: I've digested your answer and agree with all but one. With regards to turning your controllers into services, you may be adding a _lot_ of complexity for some moot decoupling. While controllers (as a service) are more specific when it comes to dependencies, that level of specificity comes at a price: time. To future readers, I recommend you go the default route of extending the Controller base class, then branch out to controller as a service as you (if you ever) need to. Thank you again @nifr for your valuable recommendations.